# Ajax jquery filter part of the html

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a Ajax call in Jquery that returns a lot of unwanted HTML. I am trying to filter out that part I want but the console just says empty string?  Could someone point me in the right direction please.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "urlencode.php",
    data: data,
    type: "POST",
    success: function (data) {
        var myd = $(data).filter("#Result").text();
        console.log(myd)
    },

    error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert(request.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: did you check why it returning unwanted html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the html data element to a dynamic div and after find your `#Result` inside it.
With `find()` method allows you to search through the descendants of these elements in the DOM tree
Try something like this:

```
$.ajax({
   url:"urlencode.php",
   data: data,
   type: "POST",
   success: function (data) {
        var myd = $('<div />').html(data).find("#Result").text();
        console.log(myd)
    },

    error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert(request.responseText);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery can do this automatically. In your `url` parameter, simply use `"urlencode.php #Result"`

Edit: forgot to mention this works if you use `.load`.

For your case, try:

```
success: function (data) {
    var myd = $($.parseHTML(data)).filter("#Result").text();
    console.log(myd)
},
```